# How to keep only unique line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i have this data

```
aaa
aaa
bbb
ddd
bbb
ccc
```

how to keep only unique lines as this result

```
ddd
ccc
```

Thanks much for any help

Comment: This will just remove duplicates. User wants to remove all lines that occur more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing a find and replace all in regex mode with:

**^(.*?\R)\1+**

and replace with nothing.

Apologies, just observed this will not work is list is not sorted.

Comment: Just observed it, I don't know how to unmark as best answer. Added a note.

Answer (score 3):

Two step

```
1st : Edit - Line Operations - Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending
2nd : replace "(?-s)^(.+\R)\1+" with nothing
```

source :https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/12490/i-want-to-keep-only-unique-lines/2

Anyone can explain the answer ? .Thanks

Comment: See @olufon answer, it works when the file is ordered.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still ending up here, you can now do:

```
Select text to operate on 
Edit->Line Operations->Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending
Edit->Line Operations->Remove Consecutive Duplicate Lines
```

Answer (score 0):

user3528679's answer works, except there's one correction in the second step.

For the regex find and replace, do not replace with nothing/blank, instead replace with the captured string in the capture group (replace with $1)

The regex selects a group of one or more consecutive duplicates. Replacement with $1 will replace the whole group with the captured string.